# Android gui design tools or framework like bootstrap

Tags: java, android-layout

I am a web developer, recently i have developed a android app using cordova. 
But my application is slow, so  i deside to developed the same app using andoid no native code. But the challenge is making same gui. i am new in android.

So my question is that what tools i use for gui design, and is there any framework like bootstrap? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this might help: http://www.androidbootstrap.com/

Github link: https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Android app is also a browser app designed in xml,  what kind of app you want to build if its an offline app you have design in xml but if it's online app (ex: playstore) you can use WebView it gives you a browser(with your webpage address hard coded in it) within an app and there you can open your mobile website.
Just like other apps do flipcart, jstdial, amazon etc.

Tools: Android Studio is best but for Start download Eclipse Atd bundle its comparatively light later you can switch to Android Studio. 
Unfortunately there is no 
and
www.androidbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do all your design in xml resource, where you can use tags like - style, selector, layer-list, item, shape etc. And these resources have to be controlled dynamically using java (in activity).

In Developers documentation of android (provided by Google) you will find details [Style elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html#style-element)